# Search for next non-blank cell, adding row and moving it with the cell next to it

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for some help with tidying up a small workbook.
There are columns I'm looking to remove but before removing them I need to get the values from the cells moved to a different column.
The Columns A and C are staying (have values that can't be removed) but columns B and C are supposed to be removed. Some rows in columns B and C have values in them. I'm looking for a code to find the value in the B column and move it to column A and then take the value from column C in the same row as the value in B was and move it to column D. I've managed to make it look for non-blank cells in the column B and move it to a new row in column A but I'm struggling to get the coressponding value in column C to move together with it. I'd appreciate any help.
My code so far:

```
    Sub InsR()

Sheets("sheet1").Select
Dim LR2 As Long, cell2 As Range, rng2 As Range
With Sheets("sheet1")
    LR2 = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell2 In .Range("B2:B" & LR2)
        If cell2.Value <> "" Then
            If rng2 Is Nothing Then
                Set rng2 = cell2

            End If

        End If
    Next cell2
    rng2.Cut
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you mean "Columns A and D are staying " not "Columns A and C are staying "

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    If cell2.Value <> "" Then
        If rng2 Is Nothing Then
            Set rng2 = cell2

        End If

    End If
```

with code like this should do it

```
   If cell2.Value <> "" Then

        ' cell2 is a cell in column B

        ' Set cell in column A equal to column B
        cell2.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell2.Value


        ' Set cell in column D equal to column C
        cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value

    End If
```